# No Module named pyb

Tags: python

I am working on a signal generator AD9833 and i am using a RaspberryPi with it.I found a python library for working with it.
The link to the library is -  https://github.com/KipCrossing/Micropython-AD9833

When i try to use this library as explained in the code below, i am not able to import the module 'pyb'. I am not able to link or install **from pyb import Pin**.
I tried various approaches.I tried this link https://pybuilder.github.io/documentation/tutorial.html#.Xd6HOOhKiUk, which describes about virtual environment. I am able to get the things as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91mmj.png), but ultimately after many hours of try, i am at same place from where i started. Please guide. I am new to programming.
I even installed the Miropython as suggested, but still the term **from pyb import Pin** is not recognized.
[Testing Micropython installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXxiY.png)

Comment: The `pyb` in that code refers to a specific module that's part of MicroPython, that talks specifically to the pyboard hardware.  It is *utterly unrelated* to pybuilder.  Your options are to rewrite the library to use GPIO functions that are supported on the RasPi, or find an AD9833 library that runs under regular Python.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Came from work early due to thanksgiving. I will try your fix on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

try to install PyBoard package

```
pip install PyBoard
```

Comment: I highly recommend using a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) or a [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/) to help organize dependencies for each project.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Came from work early due to thanksgiving. I will try your fix on Monday.

Comment: I installed the package on my laptop using pycharm but this "pyb" word is not recognized.

Comment: try to use micropythonhttps://learn.adafruit.com/micropython-basics-what-is-micropython/overview